# How to pass a two diamentional array from one activity to another activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, bundle, multidimensional-array

I have a problem with passing my **2D string** array from one **activity** to **another activity**
I tried some codes...but they show some errors

**My string array is**:

```
String[][] commuterDetails=new String[2][5];

commuterDetails=
{
   { "a", "b","c", "d","e" },
   {"f", "g","h", "i","j" }
};
```

And I tried some codes

**In first Activity**

```
Intent summaryIntent = new Intent(this, Second.class);
Bundle b=new Bundle();
b.putSerializable("Array", commuterDetails);
summaryIntent.putExtras(b);
startActivity(summaryIntent);
```

**In second activity**

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
String[][] list_array = (String[][])b.getSerializable("Array");
```

**But it showing error**

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object;
```

I am new in android, please help me

Comment: **NOBODY GAVE ME A SOLUTION ....WHO CAN ANSWER THIS QUESTION...??**

Answer (score 1):

You may define a custom class which implements `Parcelable` and contains logic to read and write 2-dimensional-array from/to Parcel. Afterwards, put that parcelable object inside Bundle for transportation.

**UPDATE**

```
public class MyParcelable implements Parcelable{

public String[][] strings;

public String[][] getStrings() {
    return strings;
}

public void setStrings(String[][] strings) {
    this.strings = strings;
}

public MyParcelable() {
    strings = new String[1][1];
}

public MyParcelable(Parcel in) {
    strings = (String[][]) in.readSerializable();
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeSerializable(strings);

}
public static final Parcelable.Creator<MyParcelable> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<MyParcelable>() {

    @Override
    public MyParcelable createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new MyParcelable(in);
    }

    @Override
    public MyParcelable[] newArray(int size) {
        return new MyParcelable[size];
    }
};
}
```

Comment: Hi Kapil Vats , i cant upvote your answer, bbecause my reputation is less than 15.. if i get this reputation .. i wil sure vote u

Comment: Almost forgot serializable! But it's ten times slower than use parcelable.

Answer (score 0):

make your commuterDetails **static** and access in other activity like this

`FirstActivity.commuterDetails[][]`

Comment: i cant access this FirstActivity.commuterDetails[][]; it showing change to static, but i have one problem ,the size of this array is allocated from another function. but i can access the array element from the method that i wrote intent and bundle

Comment: Hi Mudassar Shaheen...if you can understand my problem please reply

Comment: i cant understand but i have another solution. extend your second activity with first like SecondActivity extends FirstActivity then you can directly acces your array in second activity by using its name only

Comment: please give me a solution..when i click a button, it will go to another activity along with this array..i want this array in next activity only when a person click that button..by extending the activity ,that is not necessory